# Android-приложение вылетает при вызове метода записи в файл

Tags: java, android, файлы

Пытаюсь сделать запись настроек приложения в файл, ввиду чего использую класс написанный для "простой" java. При изменении положения Сикбара в текстовый файл должно записываться число. Но почему-то при движении Сикабара приложение вылетает:

```
package com.pacs31.calc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
SeekBar sB1;
TextView tvSetAc;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    sB1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSettingsAccuracy);
    tvSetAc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSettingsAccuracy);

    sB1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar1, int progressAccuracy, boolean fromUser) {
            int progress = progressAccuracy;

            tvSetAc.setText("Accuracy: "+progressAccuracy);

            ReadNWrite.write(Integer.toString(progressAccuracy), "settingsAccuracy");

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar1) {
        }

    });
}
}
```

Вот класс ReadNWrite, который вызывается в Сикбаре:

```
package com.pacs31.calc;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadNWrite {
private Formatter fileF;

protected void openFileW(String fileName) {
    try {
        //fileF = new Formatter("D:\\fileSettings.txt");
        fileF = new Formatter(fileName);
        //System.out.println("Added");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

protected void addRecordW(String record) {
    fileF.format(record);
}

protected void closeFileW() {
    fileF.close();
}

//---------------------------------------------

private Scanner fileS;

protected void openFileR(String fileName) {
    try {
        //fileS = new Scanner(new File("D:\\fileSettings.txt"));
        fileS = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        //System.out.println("Scanned");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

protected String readFileR() {
    String id = null;
    while (fileS.hasNext()) {
        id = fileS.next();
        //System.out.println(id);
    }
    return id;
}

protected void closeFileR() {
    fileS.close();
}

//------------------------------

protected static void write(String recordArg, String fileName){
    ReadNWrite func = new ReadNWrite();
    func.openFileW(fileName);
    func.addRecordW(recordArg);
    func.closeFileW();
}

protected static String read(String fileName){
    ReadNWrite func = new ReadNWrite();
    func.openFileR(fileName);
    String ret = func.readFileR();
    func.closeFileR();
    return ret;
}

}
```

Почему так происходит? Пробовал сделать через файл настроек типа "ключ-значение", но потерпел неудачу.

Comment: для хранения настроек в Android используется класс `SharedPreferences`, если у вас с ним получилась неудача, нужно решать эту проблему, а не подпирать самодельные костыли (которые тоже окончились неудачей)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Пошел изучать SharedPreferences.

Comment: Ну а в Вашем классе проблема в том, что Вы передаёте ему имя файла,  но не указываете путь, куда его писать.

Comment: Как указать, чтоб писал в корень приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Для записи файла нужно получить разрешение 
.
До 6 версии  это делалось через manifest после нужно ручное протверждение

Answer (score 0):

Вы установили разрешение на чтение и запись в манифесте? К тому же, на последних android Нужно проверять сей permision при попытки пользователя писать даннные. Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998400/data-directory-has-no-read-write-permission-in-android